# Check for integer overflow on pandas Series creation

Tags: python, pandas

If I have `dict` of integers like so:

```
d = {"one":2**16,
     "two": 2**16 +1}
```

what is the most efficient way to guard against integer overflow when I do:

```
pandas.Series(d, dtype="uint16")
```

In the library I am currently writing I might expect these datasets to grow to several million entries, so users may want to use smaller dtypes to control memory usage, but I want to throw a warning if they use a dtype too small to holed their values.